# How to add new data in the existing column in csv with Python?

Tags: python, excel, csv

Original existing column.

I am trying to add new data to this column (red frame) in an existing csv file.

[image]

New data.

Here is the new data that I am trying to add to the existing file.

[image]

Output.

The output file must include the new data below the old one.

[image]

I had tried several ways to do it with python.

```
import pandas as pd
#original file
file_source = r"C:\Users\Material-Library.csv"
#New data
file_dest = r"C:\Users\empty.csv"

#read the original file
df = pd.read_csv(file_source)

#Find the column of new data that I want to copy into the original file
series_col = df.loc[:,'Desc']

#save the file
series_col.to_csv(file_dest, index=False)
```

However, the data in the original file was deleted and covered by the new one. It didn't add to the original file.

Comment: can you show us what you've done?

Comment: Open the file in append mode and write your new rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your mode in [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to “a” for appending:

```py
series_col.to_csv(file_dest, index=False, mode=“a”)
```